# Typescript Anonymous class type - HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm trying to create a generic HOC, however I am having some trouble with the types

let's start simple:

```
class Abc extends React.Component<{}> {

    hello() {
    }

    render() {
        return <View />
    }
}
```

reference in JSX, no issues

```
<Abc
    ref={(r: Abc) => {
        r.hello();
    }}
/>
```

---

now lets create an anonymous, just like an HOC would return

```
const Bcd = class extends React.Component<{}> {

    hello() {
    }

    render() {
        return <View />
    }
};
```

do the same thing we did in the past

```
<Bcd
    ref={(r: Bcd) => {
        r.load()
    }}
/>;
```

now we get `TS2304: Cannot find name Bcd`, for the following `(r: Bcd)`.

I tried to change it to `(r: (typeof Bcd))`, but then it would complain that `typeof Bcd` is not compatible with `Bcd`

Am I doing something wrong or that kind of typing is not supported by typescript?

Comment: no need to explicitly type your ref var. Typescript will correctly infer the type of Bcd in your example. you can write ref={r=>{r!.hello()}} and ts should not complain.

Comment: Good point, that could unblock me, but is there any way to store the reference in a property and still have access to the type? I tried `createRef<Bcd>()`, but it complains about `Bcd` not being a type. any insights?

Answer (score 0):

In your example `Abc` is a JavaScript variable name *and* a TypeScript type name while `Bcd` is a JavaScript variable name but is *not* a TypeScript type name. `Bcd`'s type is an unnamed [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of `{hello(): void} & React.Component<{}>`. Because the type has no name you cannot reference it as a type elsewhere in your TypeScript code.